# How to import an object from another screen to another in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, reduce

I have an App from which orders are made to a restaurant.

I need that in the final message that the customer receives, which is sent from the OrderProgress.js file, informing him that his order is ready for collection, the total price of the order is also shown.

The customer selects his products and places the order from the app and a summary of the products and the price of all the products is displayed.

Then the restaurant responds from the Administrator Panel.
When the order is finished by the restaurant, in the administration panel they have a button to mark the order as finished.
When they mark the finished order, it automatically sends a notification to the client's App informing them: `**"Your Order is ready. Please can you come and pick it up. Remember that the cost of your meal was: .... "**`

Instead of receiving the notification in the App, showing the message and the total price of the order, to pay, I receive an error since it cannot find the `variable {total}`
The problem I have, I don't know how to import the object that is on the `OrderSummary.js` screen to the `OrderProgress.js` screen .

I need that in the final message that the customer receives, which is sent from the OrderProgress.js file, informing him that his order is ready for collection, the total price of the order is also shown.

[image]

I must say that I have a `State` and a `Context` to communicate the application, but there is something that I have forgotten and the App gives me an error
What should I do to add the total price to the final message that the customer receives?
What am I forgetting?

I show my files, I also show the `Context` and `State`

**file OrderSummary.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import {  Alert, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import {
  Container,
  List,
  ListItem,
  Thumbnail,
  Text,
  Left,
  Body,
  Button,
  H1
} from 'native-base'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import globalStyles from '../styles/global'
import firebase from '../firebase'

import PedidoContext from '../context/pedidos/pedidosContext'

const ResumenPedido = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  // Context del pedido realizado
  const { pedido, total, mostrarResumen, eliminarProducto, pedidoRealizado } = useContext(PedidoContext)
  //console.log(pedido)

  useEffect(() => {
    calcularTotal()
  }, [pedido])

  // Funcin para iterar sobre el pedido y los productos que añadimos y sus cantidades
  const calcularTotal = () => {
    let nuevoTotal = 0
    nuevoTotal = pedido.reduce((nuevoTotal, articulo) => nuevoTotal + articulo.total, 0)

    mostrarResumen(nuevoTotal)
  }

  // funcion para redirecionar al progreso del pedido
  const progresoPedido = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Revise el pedido',
      'Una vez realizado el pedido, no podra cambiarlo',
      [
        {
          text: 'Confirmar',
          onPress: async () => {

            // crear un objeto
            const pedidoObjeto = {
               tiempoentrega: 0,
               completado: false,
               total: Number(total),
               orden: pedido, //array
               creado: Date.now()
            }

           // console.log(pedidoObjeto)

            try {
              const pedido = await firebase.db.collection('ordenes').add(pedidoObjeto)
              pedidoRealizado(pedido.id)
              navigation.navigate("ProgresoPedido")
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }            
          }
        },
        { text: 'Revisar', style: 'cancel' }
      ]
    )
  }

  // Elimina un producto del arreglo de pedido final
  const confirmaEliminar = (id) => {
    Alert.alert(
      '¿Desea eliminar este artículo ... ?',
      'Una vez eliminado no podra recuperarlo',
      [
        {
          text: 'Confirmar',
          onPress: () => {
            // eliminar producto del state
            eliminarProducto(id)
          }
        },
        { text: 'Cancelar', style: 'cancel' }
      ]
    )

  }

  return (
    <Container style={globalStyles.contenedor}>
      <ScrollView>
      <List>
        <H1 style={globalStyles.titulo}>Product Summary</H1>
        {pedido.map((plato, i) => {
          const { cantidad, nombre, imagen, id, precio } = plato
          return (
            <List key={id + i}>
              <ListItem thumbnail>
                <Left>
                  <Thumbnail large square source={{ uri: imagen }} />
                </Left>
                <Body>
                  <Text> {nombre} </Text>
                  <Text>{cantidad} Units </Text>
                  <Text> {precio}€ each unit</Text>

                  <Button
                    onPress={() => confirmaEliminar(id)}
                    full
                    danger
                    style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                  >
                    <Text style={[globalStyles.botonTexto, { color: '#FFF' }]}>Remove</Text>
                  </Button>
                </Body>
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          )
        })}
        <Text style={globalStyles.cantidad}>Total to Pay:{total} €</Text>

        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Menu')}
          style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
          full
          rounded
          dark
        >
          <Text style={[globalStyles.botonTexto, { color: '#FFF' }]}>Keep Shopping</Text>
        </Button>

     

  
          <Button
            onPress={() => progresoPedido()}
            style={globalStyles.botonForm}
            full

          >
            <Text style={globalStyles.botonTexto}>Ordering</Text>
          </Button>
   
      </List>
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ResumenPedido
```

**file OrderProgress.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Button, Text, H1, H3 } from 'native-base'
import globalStyles from '../styles/global'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import PedidoContext from '../context/pedidos/pedidosContext'
import ResumenPedido from './ResumenPedido'    import firebase from '../firebase'
import Countdown from 'react-countdown'

const ProgresoPedido = () => {

const navigation = useNavigation()

  const { idpedido, total } = useContext(PedidoContext)

  const [tiempo, guardarTiempo] = useState(0)
  const [completado, guardarCompletado] = useState(false)

 useEffect(() => {
    const obtenerProducto = () => {
      firebase.db.collection('ordenes')
        .doc(idpedido)
        .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
          guardarTiempo(doc.data().tiempoentrega)
          guardarCompletado(doc.data().completado)
        })
    }
    obtenerProducto()
  }, [])

  // Muestra el tiempo en pantalla con Countdown
  const renderer = ({ minutes, seconds }) => {

    return (
      <Text style={styles.tiempo}>{minutes}:{seconds}</Text>
    )
  }
  return (
    <Container style={globalStyles.contenedor}>
      <View style={[globalStyles.contenido, { marginTop: 50 }]}>
        {tiempo === 0 && (
          <>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 24 }}>We have received your Order ... </Text>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 24 }}>We are calculating the delivery time</Text>
          </>
        )}

        {!completado &&  tiempo > 0 && (
          <>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}> Your order will be ready in:</Text>
            <Text>
              <Countdown
                date={Date.now() + tiempo * 60000}
                renderer={renderer} //muestra el tiempo que queda del pedido en la pantalla
              />
            </Text>
          </>
        )}

        {completado && (
          <>
            <H1 style={styles.textoCompletado}>Your order is ready</H1>
            <H3 style={styles.textoCompletado}>Please can you come and pick it up.</H3>
            <Text style={[styles.textoComplPrecio, {marginVertical: 40}]}>Remember what cost of your meal was: {total} </Text>
            <Button tyle={ [globalStyles.boton, {marginTop:200}]}
            rounded
            block
            onPress={ () => navigation.navigate("NuevaOrden")}
            >
              <Text  style={ globalStyles.botonTexto}>Exit to Menu</Text>
            </Button>
          </>
        )} 
      </View>
    </Container>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tiempo: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 60,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 80,
  },
  textoCompletado: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  textoComplPrecio: {
    textAlign: 'center', 
    fontSize: 24, 
    color: '#8E44AD'
  }
})

export default ProgresoPedido
```

**file stateOrders.js**

import React, { useReducer } from 'react'

```
import PedidoReducer from './pedidosReducer'
import PedidoContext from './pedidosContext'   
import { 
  SELECCIONAR_PRODUCTO,
  CONFIRMAR_ORDENAR_PLATO,
  MOSTRAR_RESUMEN,
  ELIMINAR_PRODUCTO,
  PEDIDO_ORDENADO
} from '../../types'

const PedidosState = props => {

  // Create initial state  const initialState = {
    pedido: [],
    plato: null,
    total: 0,
    idpedido: ''
  }

  // useReducer with dispatch to execute functions  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(PedidoReducer, initialState)

  // Select the Product that the user wants to order  const selecionarPlato = plato => {
    dispatch({
      type: SELECCIONAR_PRODUCTO,
      payload: plato
    })
  }

  // when the user confirms an order  const guardarPedido = pedido => {
    dispatch({
      type: CONFIRMAR_ORDENAR_PLATO,
      payload: pedido
    })
  }

  // Shows the total to pay in the summary of each item  const mostrarResumen = total => {
    dispatch({
      type: MOSTRAR_RESUMEN,
      payload: total
    })
  }

  // Delete the selected item from the shopping cart  const eliminarProducto = id => {
    dispatch({
      type: ELIMINAR_PRODUCTO,
      payload: id
    })
  }

  const pedidoRealizado = id => {
    dispatch({
      type: PEDIDO_ORDENADO,
      payload: id
    })
  }

  return (
    <PedidoContext.Provider
      value={{
        pedido: state.pedido,
        plato: state.plato,
        total: state.total,
        idpedido: state.idpedido,
        selecionarPlato,
        guardarPedido,
        mostrarResumen,
        eliminarProducto,
        pedidoRealizado
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </PedidoContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default PedidosState
```

Comment: Have you try to import `OrderSummary.js` into `OrderProgress.js` ?

Comment: In your example i didn't see anything about OrderSummary call (import).. i think you need to import that and call it.

Comment: If I have imported, only in the example I forgot to add it because I did it later. I have also imported State, which also has. But I don't know how to call {total}, since it is inside an Object in OrderSummary and I don't know how to call it in OrderProgress. {total}. I really don't know what to call it to bring it to ProgresoPedido. Can you offer me an idea

Comment: Which result have if you use `console.log(nameOfObject)` into your file after import file? Have you an online snippet of that problem?

Comment: Have you an online snippet of that problem?

Comment: `import pedidoObjeto from './OrderSummary' let total = pedidoObjeto
console.log(total)`.**Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.**

Comment: I think you need to create a function return object you need, if you can create an example online with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) is better for us

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.
The Object is created in a file, I have this, but I receive: "0" in the final message `const { idpedido, total } = useContext(PedidoContext)`

Comment: You need to put your code online into codesanbox i linked in my comment above, else we cannot help you

Comment: You didn't understand [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) is an online editor, we can play with the code and resolve your problem.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-field-zieto?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Seems like your example isn't complete, edit it and print `total` like your project.

Comment: I already edited the files, but it shows an error.
The app has many more files, but I show the necessary ones.
I can't think of what to show him. I will continue looking for the way on my own. Thanks